# Manhua where MC cultivates with pills to get stronger

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation, cultivation

I remember this manhua where the MC is in another world where cultivation exists, but he makes pills to break through each level. He found an ancient tool I think it was a ring or a tower but there was a lady in it teaching him martial arts and pill and weapon making to get stronger in order to break through his bottle necks but relied more on strength so that's where the pills come in and all this was to protect his sister and female teacher who is an alchemist

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tags/pill-concocting

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look through some of the comics Valorum linked, or the checklist?

Comment: Can you think of any names of people or places that appeared in the book, or any distinctive things like strange animals or what kind of clothes they wore?  Bit vague as it stands.

Answer (score 5):

This looks very close to the first book of William D. Arand's *Veilverse* series, *Cultivating Chaos*.

- another world where cultivation exists: *check*.

> “Hello,” said a rather chipper voice from nowhere. Ash’s eyes shot open and he looked around. “Hello?” he asked. “Looks like you got yourself open to the energy **of this world**. Not really sure where you’ll end up, but hey, one place is as good as another, right?”

- he makes pills to break through each level: *check*.
- with his female teacher who teaches him how to make pills but for him he already knows how to make them: *not completely sure, but I think yes*.

> “Nothing. This is my first pill,” Yue said. She looked up and stared straight at Ash. “I’m an alchemist. You made me one.”

- and he also has another teacher in his head showing him how to break through and how to make pills: *check*.

> “The Chosen One has attempted to access the data base. Would he like to see the interface?” said a voice somewhere **inside his own head**. The way it said “chosen one” almost sounded mocking.

- he does all this to protect his little sister: *adoptive sister, but check.*

> “Yes. The Deng family was **attempting to harm my sister**. So I harmed them,” Ash said. Gen gave him a wolf-like smile.

Comment: it was something like that but in a manhua

Answer (score 1):

Is it *[Born to be a God](https://www.webnovel.com/comic/born-to-be-a-god_18382225505459001)* by DongMan?

[image: Front cover of Born to be a God]

> You dare look down upon me? I'm gonna kill you! You dare touch my girls? I'm gonna make you sleep forever. In this continent, strength is the rule, and the most powerful is highly respected. A legendary talent is reborn, and the Taiyi Superb Water can make me powerful enough to shake this world. I'm Saint Ling Feng, but unfortunately, I was reborn as a trash after drinking Taiyi Super Water. But after years of hard cultivation, I finally become the best Alchemy Master with the help of Taiyi Super Water.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer by adding details about this work to demonstrate how it matches the question.  You might want to read [answer].